# Is each Lipschitz action of a finite group on the 3-sphere equivalent to a linear action?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, differential-topology, group-actions

It is [known](https://jfdmath.sitehost.iu.edu/seminar/transformationgroupsb.pdf) that each action of a compact group on the 2-dimensional $S^2$ sphere is equivalent (=conjugated) to the linear action of a subgroup of $O(3)$ on $S^2$.

On the other hand, there exists a topological action of a finite group on $S^3$ which is not equivalent to the linear action of a subgroup of $O(4)$.

But any smooth action of a finite group on $S^3$ again is equivalent to the linear action of a subgroup of $O(4)$, according to  results of Thurston and Perelman.

> What about Lipschitz actions of finite groups on $S^3$? Are they equivalent to linear actions of subgroups of $O(4)$? Or there are examples of topologically wild Lipschitz actions on $S^3$?

Comment: when you say "equivalent" there's ambiguity. I assume you mean "conjugate", but, it might mean topologically conjugate, smoothly conjugate, Lipschitz conjugate...

Comment: @YCor I use the terminology from the paper (https://jfdmath.sitehost.iu.edu/seminar/transformationgroupsb.pdf), see the last line on the page 3.

Comment: For completeness, this refers to topological conjugacy. (And hence "wild" in the question would be "topologically wild".)

Comment: Did you try to take some of the wild actions of $Z_2$ on $S^3$ and check if the construction is actually Lipschitz? These constructions are usually inductive, using a sequence of PL maps, so it would be a matter of  getting a uniform Lipschitz bound.